# Javascript `nextElementSibling` from comment undefined in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/theandybob/6wuc39d9/

When using IE, if I have a comment and try to access the `nextElementSibling` property from it, I get `undefined`. However, if I try to access `nextElementSibling` from something *not* a comment, I get my expected value. This behavior is only on IE, and I'm having a hard time trying to figure out why.

I've Googled around quite a bit, and unless I'm not searching for the right terms, I can't seem to find an answer. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div id="test">
  <!--anchor-->
  <p>
    Next Element Sibling is undefined
  </p>
</div>

<div id="test2">
  <span></span>
  <p>
    Next Element Sibling is found
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: If you have two consecutive comments, does running `nextElementSibling` on the first return the second? I'm wondering if it's somehow only looking for siblings with the same `nodeType`

Comment: A comment is not an element. It's a node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just IE, it's older browsers in general. [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) was a property of `Element`s only, not of comment nodes. Only recently the interface was changed to make the property available on other kinds of nodes as well.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!